# What possible word that begins with D and ends with Y is used in racial context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, context

I recently came across an article about [the history of chicken thieves,](https://www.gowinlaw.com/blog/2018/5/18/the-chicken-thief-is-never-pardoned) and in two instances, it made a reference to *d---y*. I'm curious to know what this means.

The first one is where they are talking about a *hungry d---y*, and the other is where a lady is talking about keeping a *d--y* away from her chicken coop and melon patch.

I am having a hard time searching for this term on Google, so any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Darky** is the word you are looking for.

OED:

> **darky | darkey**, n. ... 3. Also **darkie**. A black person, esp. from the southern U.S. Also attrib. colloq. (offensive).
>
> 1840   R. H. Dana Two Years before Mast xxxiii. 129   The darkey tried to butt him.
>
> 1848   J. R. Lowell Biglow Papers 1st Ser. ii. 24   I'd an idee thet they were built arter the darkie fashion all.
>
> 1883   Cent. Mag. 27 132   The manners of a corn-field darky.